# Как работает оператор continue

Tags: python, операторы

Для чего в python используется оператор `continue`? Вот здесь, к примеру:

```
while True:
    s = input('Введите что-нибудь: ')
    if s == 'выход':
        print('Осуществляется выход из программы...')
        break
    if len(s) < 3:
        print('Слишком мало')
        continue
    print('Введенная строка достаточной длины')
```

Если убрать `continue`, то программа будет работать точно также?

Comment: Скрипт невалидный, подправьте его. ЗЫ, оператор используется в циклах для прерывания дальнейшего выполнения кода в теле цикла и начала выполнения следующей итерации цикла

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оператор continue начинает следующий проход цикла, минуя оставшееся тело цикла.
Вот ссылка на урок по циклам

https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/cikly-for-i-while-operatory-break-i-continue-volshebnoe-slovo-else.html

Answer (score 0):

Как вам уже написали: оператор continue прерывает текущую итерацию и начинает следующую, это некий эквивалент `next()`.

Comment: Чтобы объяснить `continue` через `next`, нужно сначала объяснить `next`. Ну это не очень удачная аналогия: `next` работает с итераторами, и "дергает" итератор извне, при этом никакая часть кода итератора не прерывается и не пропускается. А `continue` работает только внутри цикла, и просто пропускает часть цикла.

Comment: Я не педагог и никогда им не стану. Я всего лишь написал, что это эквивалент, чтобы у человека появилась примерная картина чего он хочет понять

Comment: Проблема в том, что это не эквивалент, поэтому  может создать разве что ложное ощущение понимания.

Comment: Эквивале́нт — нечто равноценное или соответствующее в **каком-либо отношении** чему-либо

Comment: Спасибо за цитату из википедии, но `continue` и `next` не эквивалентны ни в каком отношении.

Comment: continue переходит к следующей итерации? Да. next() переходит к следующей итерации? Да. Дело лишь только в том что continue "сбивает" текущий блок кода и начинает его заново, а next() заканчивает его "образно", так сказать в уме.